# PGSQL 9.2 / OpenErp 7 / Restore database from plain directory

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I cannot restore a database from a plain directory
I tried with CHATGPT, at the end, pg_dump & pg_restore don't work on plain directories, only on valid backup made with PGADMIN or PG_backup
My aim is to restore the database from the plain directory backed up with windows, and I know that I have to modify the table of databases including the KEY OID also
Thanks in advance.